# How to get records right arranged in windows batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have file s_result.txt as:

```
AAA,BBB,CCC
DDD,EEE
FFF,GGG
HHH,III,JJJ
...
```

And I try to get the sf_result.txt like this:

```
AAA,BBB
AAA,CCC
DDD,EEE
FFF,GGG
HHH,III
HHH,JJJ
...
```

I used script as below:

```
REM Transfer s_result.txt to sf_result.txt
DEL sf_result.txt
Echo. 2>sf_result.txt
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in (s_result.txt) do (
If %%c EQU [] (
ECHO %%a,%%b>>sf_result.txt
) else (
ECHO %%a,%%b>>sf_result.txt
ECHO %%a,%%c>>sf_result.txt
)
)
```

I got this result.txt instead:

```
AAA,BBB
AAA,CCC
DDD,EEE
DDD,
FFF,GGG
FFF,
HHH,III
HHH,JJJ
...
```

How can I get the right result?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have already been great answers provided with some smart approaches.
However, I want to stick to the code you posted here.

The main problem is the line `if %%c EQU []`, because it compares the third token with the literal string `[]`; the third token can be `CCC`, `JJJ`, or an empty string, according to your example, so the condition is never going to be fulfilled.
To correct that, you should write `if "%%c"==""` instead.

You could further improve your script by doing a single [redirection `>`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to the output file rather than creating it in advance and appending multiple times; just put the entire `for /F` loop in between parentheses and redirect the whole block.

So here is the corrected and improved code:

```cmd
rem Transfer s_result.txt to sf_result.txt
> "sf_result.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ("s_result.txt") do @(
        if "%%c"=="" (
            echo %%a,%%b
        ) else (
            echo %%a,%%b
            echo %%a,%%c
        )
    )
)
```

The `@` symbol prevents command echoes of the loop body to be written to the output file as well. If there is `@echo off` placed at the beginning of your script you do no longer need that symbol.

Of course this code cannot handle lines with more than three tokens correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse line-by-line, use `for /F`.  If you want to tokenize word-by-word on a single line, use `for` without the `/F`.  Also, in a basic `for` loop, Windows already tokenizes on unquoted commas with no need to specify a delimiter.  (It also tokenizes on spaces, tabs, and semicolons.)  With this in mind, the solution is actually pretty simple.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=," %%I in ("test.txt") do (
    for %%x in (%%J) do (
        echo(%%I,%%x
    )
)
```

Output:

> AAA,BBB
>   AAA,CCC
>   DDD,EEE
>   FFF,GGG
>   HHH,III
>   HHH,JJJ

Answer (score 1):

I do like [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51073972/6811411)s clever approach  (+1).

To overcome the implications he mentions I think of a recursive approach.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\28\SO_51073893.cmd 
@echo off & setlocal
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-2* delims=," %%A in ("test.txt") do Call :Sub "%%A" "%%B" "%%C"
Goto :Eof
:Sub
Echo %~1,%~2
if "%~3" neq "" for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%D in (%3) do Call :Sub %1 "%%D" "%%E"
```

With a slightly changed file `test.txt` I get this output:

```
> SO_51073893.cmd
AAA,B=B
AAA,C;C
DDD,EEE
FFF,GGG
HHH,I I
HHH,JJJ
```